# QGIS 2.8 PrintComposer, no coordinates shown

Tags: qgis, coordinates, print-composer, mac

I tested under MacOS 10.10.3 and 10.9.5 now: In the QGIS v2.8 Print Composer I don´t get coordinates shown when I want to create a map sheet and activate "Draw coordinates". I can do all settings under "Item Properties" but can only see the coordinates when I finally export the map as e.g. PDF. It´s of course quite unproductive to export everytime a PDF to see the changes I made...
I just upgraded from QGIS 2.4 and there it was working fine. Any Ideas?

Comment: Hello there! You write that you are using QGIS 2.8. Sure about that? Kyngchaos (http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) provides version 2.8.1-1 as the latest version for Mac OS X. If you are not using 2.8.1-1 upgrade and check if it works. If you are indeed using a QGIS version 2.8 for Mac OS X you should check your source. Could be a bad compile.

Comment: Sorry for the (very) late reply. I checked now the Version and to be sure reinstalled QGIS 2.8.1-1 from the Kyngchaos website (as I did before too). It´s still the same that I can´t see the frame (e.g. "Zebra") and the coordinates when I attempt to draw a grid. Only when I export it I see the frame and the numbers.